# Como puedo hacer un autocomplete y mostrar los resultados en una tabla

Tags: html, jquery, css, html5, css3

Alguien podría indicarme como realizar un autocomplete igual al de la imagen cuyos resultados lo muestra en una tabla propiamente del autocomplete. Espero sus comentarios y/o sugerencias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tomando en cuenta que los valores de respuesta los tienes dentro del html en una tabla o lista ocultos, el siguiente script hecho con jQuery hace la coincidencia según la palabra escrita por el ususario y lo muestra.

```
    $("#filter").keyup(function(){
        // Recupera el texto del campo de entrada y restablece el conteo a cero
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
        // Recorrer la tabla de respuestas
        $("#table tr td").each(function(){
            // Si el elemento de la tabla no contiene la frase de texto, difumína.
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();
            // Mostrar el elemento de la tabla si la frase coincide e incrementa el contador a 1
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });
        // Actualiza el contador
        var numberItems = count;
        // Esto solo muestra en numero de coincidencias
        $("#filter-count").text("Coincidencias = "+count);
    });
```

Solo necesitas renombrar los id tanto de tu input del buscador, como el de los datos ocultos que quieres mostrar, si los quisieras o tuvieras en una lista cambiarias #table tr td por #lista li.